# jQuery select html content from <div> except first paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="test">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>
```

How can I get html from this ? Except the first

. SO basically I need to get 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows

Comment: `.not( ":first")`

Comment: $("div.test p:not(:first)").html() - this gets only second paragraph

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `not` jquery function like this:

```js
let el = $("p").not( ":first");
console.log(el.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.test').find('p').not(':first')
```

inside node with `class === test`, find all p elements that are not first element

Answer (score 0):

try this snppet

explanation for not function:

- All selectors are accepted inside `:not()`, for example: `:not(div a)` and `:not(div,a).`
- The `.not()` method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a `:not()` selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.
  explanation for first():
- This method does not accept any arguments.
- Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var p=$(".test > p:not(:first)").text();
 alert(p);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid using `alert()` in code snippets. `console.log()` will print it nicely on the bottom of your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To get the html of the element after removing the first paragraph:

```js
var clone = $('.test').clone()
clone.find('p').first().remove();
console.log(clone.prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As written by @Brian, try to do as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").not(":first").css("color", "red");
});
```

instead of `.css`, you can set what you prefer.